# How to pass a DateTime.Today as a parameter using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, restsharp

i'm making a console application to send email, im using the Qualtrics API REST, so i'm creating the request with **RestSharp**, the call that i'm using is for creating an email list, one of its parameters is the name of that list, but i want to put automatically the current date when it was created, this is the call:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
  {
            var client = new RestClient("https://qualtrics.com/API/v3/mailinglists");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "XXXX");
            request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("X-API-TOKEN", "XXXX");
            request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\r\n    \"category\": \"Test Category\",\r\n    \"libraryId\": \"XXXX\",\r\n    \"name\": \"Application Test\"\r\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
  }
```

This part: *"name\": \"**Application Test**\"* is what i want to modify to put in "Application Test" the current date, Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `\"date\":" + DateTime.Today.ToString()` I would guess? P.S. It would be better not to build your JSON by hand but to serialise it from a C# object.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks!, that is what i needed

Comment: No problem. I've written it as the proper answer, if you'd like to accept it - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\"date\":" + DateTime.Today.ToString()
```

will give you want you want.

P.S. It would be better in future not to build your JSON by hand but to serialise it from a C# object.